# not getting headers passed with RestTemplate.getForObject

Tags: java, spring

I am newbie using Spring . I am working on a code trying to pass headers using **restTemplate.getForObject**

client side :

```
String userServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/SampleRest/api/user/";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
restTemplate.getForObject(userServiceUrl + "{id}",User.class,HttpMethod.GET,headers) ;
```

however on server the request header  "Authentication" is not passed at all . there is no header "Authentication"

```
requestHeaders.get("Authorization").get(0) //yields null exception
```

*I cannot use restTemplate.exchange*

what am I doing wrong ?

Help will greatly appreciated

Comment: Should it not be requestHeaders.get("Authentication").get(0)?

Comment: Why? I set a header with "Authorization" I expect to get the same one on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to pass headers in `getForObject` method of `restTemplate`.

You can implement `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to set the headers if you don't want to use `exchange`. You can also overwrite `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`

Answer (score 0):

We can use it in Spring boot for GET Method  in the below manner :

@SpringBootApplication

public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    try{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders = this.createHeaders();
    ResponseEntity<String> response;
    response  = restTemplate.exchange("<url>",HttpMethod.GET,new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders),String.class);
    log.info(response.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception"+e);
    }


}

private HttpHeaders createHeaders(){
    HttpHeaders headers =  new HttpHeaders(){
          {            
             set( "Authorization", "3ee140");
          }
       };

       return headers;
}
```

}